# Thymleaf controller request mapping binging issue

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to thymleaf and at first i used simple requestmapping and thymleaf th:action and th:object to bind controller methods. But after adding class level requestmapping i cannot view my html.

below is my controller class code where i redirect to login page.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("mylogin", new Credentials());
        return "login";

    }
    }
```

below is my html page.

```
<form class="user" th:action="@{/project/login}" th:object="${mylogin}" method="POST">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" id="user_name" name="username"
                                                class="form-control form-control-user"

                                                placeholder="Enter Email Address..." />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                                                class="form-control form-control-user"
                                                placeholder="Password" />
                                        </div>

                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"
                                            name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit" th:text="Login"></button>
                                    </form>
```

after adding **@RequestMapping("/project")** in class i cannot fetch html. If i remove this @RequestMapping("/project") and change **th:action="@{/project/login}"** to **th:action="@{/login}"** my code works.

What can  be the problem for such issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change This Request mapping this way  **/login** with class level requestmapping and try again:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("mylogin", new Credentials());
        return "login";
    }
```

OR

```
 @GetMapping("/login")
 public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("mylogin", new Credentials());
        return "login";
    }
```

Comment: Your class level request mapping  @RequestMapping("/project")  and in Action  @GetMapping("/login") so for this action url willbe th:action="@{/project/login}"
 
why you used this  th:action="@{/timeproject/login}"

Comment: sorry i forgot to change that. But thats not the issue.